# Homebrew broken? Ruby Broken? Can't run brew or reinstall

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I can't run anything in brew. I do not know what has happened. I tried to install Jekyll and I started getting this error.

```
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 23: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

Also, ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

Here is what I typed:

```
~]$ brew install ruby                                (gh-pages✱)
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 23: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

Comment: Does `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby` exist? If you've done something to your system Ruby, you should restore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching over to rbenv to install and manage your ruby:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

Afterwards you'll still need to add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to your profile. You'll only ever have to do this once.

```
$ rbenv install 2.0.0p481
```

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks, there was another issue.  and I have resolved.